# SharePoint Search on the second webapp

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

I have a question, we have 1 Web App which our Intranet exist in it and the search works fantastic. I have created 2 webApp (extranet) and added around 30000 documents in it. My question is how I can show the documents in the extranet when users search for document in Intranet.

regards

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is configure a start address for the Extranet in the Search Service Application. You also need to grant access to the documents. Once a user has permissions to the content and search crawls the content they will show up in the search results.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the emai, i am not too sure when you say configure a start address, is it adding Extranet webApp URL to Content Sources?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Thanks Matt, its already added, and the result is all from the intranet nothing comes from extranet.

Comment: Does your account have access? What is in the crawl logs?

Comment: My account is Farm account, there are 16 errors on the Crawl Log which is "The filtering process could not be initialized when trying to process this item. Verify that the file extension is a known type and the item is not corrupt." when i search on the extranet it works as expected however i need to search the extranet document in Intranet.

Comment: You should not use the Farm account for crawling. That is a bad practice. You should just use a separate crawl account. What items are failing in the crawl?

Comment: sure, i have created seperate account for crawling.

Comment: basiccally nothing is coming through from the extranet, only documents from the intranet coming through.

Comment: Are you seeing successes in the crawl logs? You should see specific documents in the crawl logs that you can then search for.

Comment: i can see 2,323,43 success, but the thing is all of them coming from intranet. some how i need to bring extranet documents in to intranet crawl results.

Comment: Are you crawling the extranet?

Comment: sorry to late reply, yes, there all crawling. but no result.

Comment: And you are seeing success in the logs? Can you access the successful documents with a normal account (not the farm account)? Can you search for them by title or URL?